# Error when retrieving an object after storing it

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have two servlets:

One where I store a User:

```
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(PersistentUser.class.getSimpleName(), "alfred");
    PersistentUser user = new PersistentUser();
    user.setKey(key);
    user.setLogin("alfred");

    try {
         pm.makePersistent(user);
    } finally {
         pm.flush();
         pm.close();
    }
```

And another one where I want to read it:

```
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(PersistentUser.class.getSimpleName(), "alfred");
    PersistentUser e;
    try {
        e = pm.getObjectById(PersistentUser.class, k);
        log.info(e.getLogin());
        response.getOutputStream().println(e.getLogin());
    } finally {
        pm.flush();
        pm.close();
    }
```

So, I don't get any problem when making the user persistent but I cannot retrieve the object in the other servlet getting this error:

javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: Could not retrieve entity of kind PersistentUser with key PersistentUser("login")

I am using the standard PMF class. My PersistentUser class is the one below:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class PersistentUser implements Serializable{

    @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String login;

    public PersistentUser() {}

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
```

}

and my jdoconfig file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

       <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
           <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
           <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
           <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
       </persistence-manager-factory>
    </jdoconfig>
```

Comment: What is `u.getLogin()` and how does it relate to the hard-coded string `"alfred"` and the later call to `usr.setLogin("alfred")`?  How do `u`, `user`, and `usr` relate to one another?

Comment: my mistake, they are the same. I edited it, thank you